# How to make Kicad alow P-MOSFET as switch without ERC problems?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, kicad

I have a P-MOSFET which is acting as a switch. However, I get errors as seen in the image. How should I resolve this issue? I know i just could don't bother since i know it will work but I rather not.

[image: Screan dump]

I have tried using PWR_FLAG but that do not work either. Is all PWR_FLAGS connected and that is why that results in strange behavior?

/Johan

Comment: PWR_FLAGs are not connected together. To solve your problem you can edit the mosfet symbol and set its pins as passive, you can connect anything to a passive pin type.

Comment: That's what happens when you make a DRC system that's too anal. There's absolutely no reason that it should be illegal to connect a collector/drain or emitter/source directly to a power source. Also, you need some resistors connected between the gate and source of each of your MOSFETs.

Comment: I see this as closed. Thank you both if i had the rep to up vote I would!

Comment: @VladimirCravero, you should post your comment as an answer so this question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: I agree and will mark as solved.

Comment: I added something, that's a very thin answer anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PWR_FLAGs are not connected together. To solve your problem you can edit the mosfet symbol and set its pins as passive, you can connect anything to a passive pin type.

This solution is kind of a hack though, but it can't be helped because the kicad pin types are somewhat limited. When you use such a trick be extra sure to connect everything as intended because the DRC won't help you.